# beforeunload Or onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I'm stuck working out which one of these I should be using: `beforeunload` or `onbeforeunload` They both seem to be doing very similar things, but with different browser compatibility.

**Some context**:

I have a form. On page load I serialise the form and save it in a variable. If the user leaves the page I serialise the form and compare the two, to see if there's been any changes. However, if the form is submitted then the event should not be fired.

**Example 1**

I have this working as expected. I just don't understand the differences between the two:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if(strOnloadForm != strUnloadForm)
        return "You have unsaved changes.";
}
```

With this line to stop it firing when you save the form (bound to `.submit()`)

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

**Example 2**

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) {
    if(strOnloadForm != strUnloadForm)
        event.returnValue = "You have unsaved changes.";
});
```

With this line to stop it firing when you save the form (bound to `.submit()`)

```
window.removeEventListener("beforeunload");
```

**What the documentation says**

I've read the documentation for [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.onbeforeunload) and [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload).
Under the `onbeforeunload` section [**Notes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Notes) it states:

> You *can* and *should* handle this event through [window.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event. More documentation is available there.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Notes)</sup>

Which makes me think I **should be using the latter**. However the documentation for [removeEventHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) says this:

> `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` are not present in older browsers. You can work around this by inserting the following code at the beginning of your scripts, allowing use of `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` in implementations which do not natively support it.<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#Polyfill_to_support_older_browsers)</sup>

Could somebody please shed some light on the differences for these please, and the best one to use?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Notes</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#Polyfill_to_support_older_browsers</sub>

Comment: It's the exact same event, but when using addEventListener you always leave of the "on" part.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense that it's actually just a different way of firing the same event.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`window.onbeforeunload = function () {/**/}` will override any existing handlers and replace it with your own.

`window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {/**/});` will add a new handler.

`addEventListener` is far preferred. In older browsers (that is: IE6 maybe IE7) you can use `attachEvent`.

You'll commonly see code like:

```
function addEvent(object, event_type, event_handler) {
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(event_type, event_handler, false);
    } else {
        object.attachEvent("on" + event_type, handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. It makes perfect sense that `onbeforeunload` will override any handlers whereas using `addEventListener` adds one, once you know.

Comment: There is a small error in the code, in the else statement is `object.attachEvent("on" + event_type, event_handler);` (note the event_handler instead of handler)

Comment: @Néstor This post is almost 10 years old. Are you still programming for IE7?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was so old this answer. In the end I didn't use it as it was another error. Once I checked compatibility tables I found it was no necessary to do it, but I already had posted the comment... No, happy to don't need to be IE7 compatible any more