# Confirm navigation of 'Go Back' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to show users a confirmation popup when the 'back button' is clicked. I am using `React Router v3`, so I cannot use `<Prompt/>` of React Router v4.

Here is what I would like to achieve:

- when a user clicks 'go back' or 'refresh' with unsaved data on a form, the browser shows a confirmation popup 'Yes' and 'No' to either leave or stay.

I have tried few things:

**1) setRouteLeaveHook** (React Router v3) [React Router v3 doc](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md)

```
  componentDidUpdate() {

  ...
  if (isDirty)  // denoting that there is unsaved work
    this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(
      this.props.route,
      () => { return 'Unsaved data will be lost' }
    );
  }
```

- In this case, I have wrapped my component with `withRouter` so that I could access `this.props.router`
- I could not achieve my goal as I did the following

  1. Try click 'go back' from `www.website.com/about` to `www.website.com`
  2. The popup message shows up, and I click 'No' to stay on the same page
  3. Although the content (component) is the same, the url is changed back to `www.website.com`

**2) 'beforeunload' and 'popstate'**

```
  componentDidUpdate() {

  ...
    if (isDirty)  // denoting that there is unsaved work
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleBeforeUnload);
      window.addEventListener('popstate', this.handleOnPopState);
    }
  }

  handleBeforeUnload = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const msg = 'Are you sure?';
    e.returnValue = msg;
    return msg;
  }

  handleOnPopState = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // how can I prevent here?
  }
```

- Here, the confirmation message pops up and works as it should be when I try to `reload`.
- However, no confirmation nor it prevents 'go back' when I click the back button.

What is the best way to prevent accidental navigation from the users?
Any help or suggestion is appreciated!!

p.s. I cannot upgrade to React Router v4

Comment: [solution for detecting and stop browser back button events.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60740208/10156778)

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is having the same issue, please refer to my solution here:

[Detecting user leaving page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page/50388073#50388073)