# onbeforeunload() function not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).bind("onbeforeunload", function () {
    return true;
});
```

Im trying to bind the onbeforeunload eventhandler in jquery to the window but its not giving the Leave Site? prompt when you click the close button any idea why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beforeunload Or onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001125/beforeunload-or-onbeforeunload)

Comment: There's no *event* with the name `onbeforeunload` - try `beforeunload` - see the linked question for more info

Comment: this code supposed to provide an alert message while closing the window right?

Comment: not working with beforeunload either

Comment: @freedomn-m my bad ill make the question more clear

Comment: Check your browser console for messages:  At one point I got:  `Blocked attempt to show a 'beforeunload' confirmation panel for a frame that never had a user gesture since its load`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.bind()` has been deprecated for `.on()` for quite some time. Also, any errors in the console?